# Function notation for specifying (co)domain and mapping at once

Tags: functions, notation, lambda-calculus

I am looking for conventions of spelling out a function type together with a mapping. I have found some possibilities:

1. using intermediate words:  $$f \colon R \to R\ \text{where}\ x \mapsto x^2$$
2. writing stuff above each other:
   $$\begin{align}f \colon &R \to R \\ &x \mapsto x^2\end{align}$$
3. putting another colon in between:
   $$f \colon R \to R : x \mapsto x^2$$

There are also various possibilities to write the mapping part

- $f \colon x \mapsto x^2$
- $f(x) = x^2$
- $\lambda(x).x^2$

Is there a prevalent way of writing both parts of the definition?

Comment: $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \colon x \mapsto x^2$ is the most common I see for full formality.

Comment: As far as I know, all of these are more or less common except for $\lambda x.x^2$, which is typically only used in a context where people know about lambda calculus. In your (1), I would typically expect $f$ to be repeated in the mapping part if there is a separating word (so "$f: R \to R$, where $f:x\mapsto x^2$"), and in your (2) I would expect $f$ to be on the line with the $R \to R$, not with the mapping part. Finally, you repeatedly write $R \to R^2$; presumably you just mean $R \to R$.

Comment: You could also use something like $f: x ∈ R ↦ x^2 ∈ R$ or $f: R ∋ x ↦ x^2 ∈ R$, but it is practical only with small formulas I guess.